# Newest STS is extract only? no installation?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

I've noticed the new STS is extract only and nothing is installed unlike the previous versions.

Question:
1. I want to run Maven in the cmd. Can I use what STS is using? If yes, where is it so I could add it in my env vars. If I can't use it, so it means I need to install maven separately although STS already has one?

Can anyone clarify this matter? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Maven extension of Eclipse (M2e) that is part of STS has an embedded Maven version. You can just download that Maven version (check out the settings - maven - maven installations) from Apache and install it separately to use it on the command line.